# Post HTML tag (codes) as string with ASP.net MVC & JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm trying to post a Form through a MVC Model into a Save function in a controller. I'm also using tinymce on the client side which results a HTML code based string such like `<p> Content text blah blah ...</p>`.

The problem is that I cannot post a string that includes `<p> something </p>` But surprisingly, `< p > something < / p >` this string (with spaces after "<") has NO problem. But, I cannot handle this html code and make these spaces before posting every time. There must be a better way.

So, How can I post a string that includes HTML code through $.post method? (If you must know, this project is a Content Management System. So, I have to save the HTML based content text into a SQL table.) I saw by debugging, the post action **does not even** reach to the Controller and I think this is a only javascript problem, am I right?

Here is the code I am using:
**Javascript**

---

```
function JqueryFromPost(formId) {

  var form = $(formId);
  var action = form.attr("action");
  var serializedForm = form.serializeArray();

  $.post(action, serializedForm, function (data) {
      //Getting the data Result here...
  });
}
```

**CS Code**

---

```
   [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult SaveArticle(ArticleModel model)
   {
       JsonResult JResult = new JsonResult();

       if (ModelState.IsValid)
           //I do the saving here ending with "JResult.Data = "Success";" (this could also be Failed. So, its just to explain)

       return JResult;
   }
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

ASP.NET has built-in request validation that automatically helps protect against XSS and HTML injection attacks. If you want to explicitly disable this validation you could decorate the action you are posting to with the [`[ValidateInput(false)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]   
public ActionResult SaveArticle(ArticleModel model)
{
    var JResult = new JsonResult();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
    }
    return JResult;
}
```

Also if you are running this on ASP.NET 4.0 for this attribute to take effect you need to add the following to your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

And if you are using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 you could decorate only the property on your model that requires HTML with the [`[AllowHtml]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
public class ArticleModel 
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Also in your javascript function you probably want [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) instead of [`serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/):

```
function JqueryFromPost(formId) {
    var form = $(formId);
    $.post(form.action, form.serialize(), function (data) {
        //Getting the data Result here...
    });
}
```

Comment: Very helpful. But I got it working in .NET 4.0 without `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />`

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use ValidateInput(false) as MSN said here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708755.aspx 
Just use `[AllowHtml]` on your model property you want take html.

```
[AllowHtml]
public String htmlContainer { get; set; }
```

Additionally I think that is better if you encode html and then post it to server.

Answer (score 3):

Using **[ValidateInput(false)]** is a very bad practice which leads to many security breaches, 
**[AllowHtml]** on a model property is more secured and reliable way of doing this. **But there is a much cleaner solution if you can't use a model property.**

Simply **Encode** the text on Client Side(mycase **javascript**), **Decode** it on the serve side(**Controller** **function**).
I used the below for my vb.net project.

`var SearchStringValue = <p> some blah...blah data </p>`

Now **encoding** the above variable.

`var encodedSearchStringValue = window.escape(document.getElementById('SearchStringValue').value)`

now pass encodeSearchStringValue to controller using ajax.

In the controller just **decode** the variable to get `<p> some blah...blah data </p>.`

```
Dim SearchStringValue = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodeSearchStringValue)
```

Hope this helps......... :)