# How to bypass or detect an html tag input to prevent runtime bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm working with comment section page which allows user to input messages and I would like to know how to bypass and capture the data even if the user inputs an html element without any errors...Thanks.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4759693/326543) give you a hint?

Comment: `comment = comment.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;");` might be a start... for URLs there is something like UrlEncode/UrlDecode. There should be something similar for HTML.