# Sending HTML to Controller using Ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to figure out why my Ajax query is not being sent to the controller when trying to send HTML data.

Using this simple POST to send the data:

```
        var contentFull = $("#contract").html();

        var url2 = '@Url.Action("SavePDF", "FRP")';
        $.ajax({
            url: url2,
            type: 'POST',
            contenttype: 'text/plain',
            async: true,
            data: {
                Content: contentFull
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                CustomAlert.render(XMLHttpRequest);
                CustomAlert.render(textStatus);
                CustomAlert.render(errorThrown);
                CustomAlert.render("Error while posting SendResult");
            },
            success: function (result) {
                CustomAlert.render("Yey?");
            }

        });
```

When changing contentFull to a simple string ("test"); the function SavePDF will activate and the content will be filled correctly.
When using the POST as is; the succes function will fire off, but the SavePDF function is completely ignored.

I've been looking like crazy figuring out what the reason could be. 
First thought was the character limit issue which should be solved by using POST.

Comment: Open your browser console. I'm pretty sure there will be errors there.

Comment: Have been checking; no output while running the ajax post
EDIT: I have been testing with IE 11 though, will test on Chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery send HTML data through POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078909/jquery-send-html-data-through-post)

Comment: Maybe your PHP script only accepts GET requests?

Comment: This might be helpful: [Post HTML tag (codes) as string with ASP.net MVC & JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759681/post-html-tag-codes-as-string-with-asp-net-mvc-jquery)

Comment: Try to set in your data property form.serialize() to send all form serialized automatically, and no need to say the contenttype actually.

Comment: @Justinas I can't see how `PHP` would relate to `ASP.Net MVC Controllers`?

Comment: Edit your question with content of this from console: `console.log($("#contract").html());`.

Comment: @Legionar I have done so; I don't understand the plethora of <strong> tags at the bottom since they are not written in the original cshtml..

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this as solved. To do this, we just add an answer below, as you have done already - thanks! You may self-accept it if you wish i.e. click the tick to mark it as done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer found below! https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ASP.NET_Request_Validation

Asp.net request validation ignored my request because of security XSS issues. By using the tag [ValidateInput(false)] in my MVC Controller; the function works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Since i still can't comment, i'll use answering function instead.
I don't think you need to specify contenttype and async, async is true by default, contenttype text/plain will not allow you to send html content.

```
var contentFull = $("#contract").html();

        var url2 = '@Url.Action("SavePDF", "FRP")';
        $.ajax({
            url: url2,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                Content: contentFull
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                CustomAlert.render(XMLHttpRequest);
                CustomAlert.render(textStatus);
                CustomAlert.render(errorThrown);
                CustomAlert.render("Error while posting SendResult");
            },
            success: function (result) {
                CustomAlert.render("Yey?");
            }

        });
```

Comment: Same error as I have been having before.. Sending normal text in contentFull works perfectly; having a bunch of HTML in there (in string format), doesn't

Comment: what framework you use? some framework will filter XSS when user post string. so please check your framework that does it be filtered. Sometimes there are some WAF will filter XSS as well.

Comment: I have updated my comment at above.you should turn xss protection off and try. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ASP.NET_Request_Validation

Comment: @user2352577L THIS!! gives me a lot of hope! Thank you, I will check this out!

Comment: DING DING DING!! Correct answer!! Thank you so much @user2352577L

Comment: But there is a risk which that someone can using xss for further hacking actions. If you can edit, just leave the xss checking for this value.

Comment: @user2352577L  It's a function that is deeply nested in an authentication cycle which should only be available to users who have completed the functions of the program.

Answer (score 0):

```
var contentFull = $("#contract").html();
var url2 = '@Url.Action("SavePDF", "FRP")';

$.ajax({
    url: url2,
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    data: {
        Content: contentFull
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        CustomAlert.render(XMLHttpRequest);
        CustomAlert.render(textStatus);
        CustomAlert.render(errorThrown);
        CustomAlert.render("Error while posting SendResult");
    },
    success: function (result) {
        CustomAlert.render("Yey?");
    }
});
```

Comment: This will work fine. you were added  contenttype: 'text/plain', so it will accepts on only text.

Comment: Will try this now; As far as I remember; this is the function I originally started from
EDIT: Same problem here; changing Content: "Test" works perfectly; having contentFull there does not fire SavePDF in the controller